# Vuetfiy v-text-label has no border

Tags: vuetify.js

So I have tried to fix this in multiple different ways and I know Vuetify is updated because I have reinstalled it in NPM before I used it.

I have some screenshots of the current problem but the weird part is its working in another project I am using and its running the same libraries.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt7qN.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXowY.png

Code for uncolored component

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>XRPLife Interfaces</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <v-app>

        <div id="test">
            <v-text-field label="Testing" v-model="test"></v-text-field>
        </div>

    </v-app>

    <script src="libraries/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = new Vue({
            el: "#test",

            data: {
                test: "",
            },

            methods: {

            }
        })

    </script>
</body>
```

How it works with the SAME library but just a different project
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwOjF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect nesting of HTML tags for the application. Try this:

```
<div id="test">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field label="Testing" v-model="test"></v-text-field>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/ga8kpzp0/ ]

Comment: That fixed the issue for me. I really appreciate you helping me. Just weird I didn't do that in any other of my projects and they were fine with just the v-app. I will go back and fix them all now XD.